# What process is listening on a certain port on Solaris?

Tags: unix, solaris

So I log into a Solaris box, try to start Apache, and find that there is already a process listening on port 80, and it's not Apache. Our boxes don't have lsof installed, so I can't query with that. I guess I could do:

```
pfiles `ls /proc` | less
```

and look for "port: 80", but if anyone has a better solution, I'm all ears! Even better if I can look for the listening process without being root. I'm open to both shell and C solutions; I wouldn't mind having a little custom executable to carry with me for the next time this comes up.

Updated: I'm talking about generic installs of solaris for which I am not the administrator (although I do have superuser access), so installing things from the freeware disk isn't an option. Obviously neither are using Linux-specific extensions to fuser, netstat, or other tools. So far running pfiles on **all** processes seems to be the best solution, unfortunately. If that remains the case, I'll probably post an answer with some slightly more efficient code that the clip above.

Comment: @AlanH `netstat` won't tell you the process.

Comment: In Solaris 11.2 `netstat -aun` gives you the pid and the command.
See @nolan6000's answer.

Answer (score 29):

I found this script somewhere. I don't remember where, but it works for me:

```
#!/bin/ksh

line='---------------------------------------------'
pids=$(/usr/bin/ps -ef | sed 1d | awk '{print $2}')

if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
   read ans?"Enter port you would like to know pid for: "
else
   ans=$1
fi

for f in $pids
do
   /usr/proc/bin/pfiles $f 2>/dev/null | /usr/xpg4/bin/grep -q "port: $ans"
   if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
      echo $line
      echo "Port: $ans is being used by PID:\c"
      /usr/bin/ps -ef -o pid -o args | egrep -v "grep|pfiles" | grep $f
   fi
done
exit 0
```

Edit: Here is the original source:
[[Solaris] Which process is bound to a given port ?](http://blogs.oracle.com/JoachimAndres/entry/solaris_which_process_is_bound1)

Comment: This works, but requires root for pfiles to query processes not owned by the current user.

Comment: MAJOR CAVEAT here!  From the pfiles man page: <br>WARNINGS</br>
The following proc tools stop their target  processes  while inspecting them and reporting the results: <b>pfiles</b>, pldd, and pstack. A process can do nothing while it  is  stopped.  Stopping  a heavily used process in a production environment...can cause severe bottlenecks and  even hangs  of these processes, causing them to be unavailable to users.  <b>Some  databases  could  also  terminate abnormally.</b>   Because of this, stopping a UNIX process in a production environment should be avoided.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a one-liner:

```
ps -ef| awk '{print $2}'| xargs -I '{}' sh -c 'echo examining process {}; pfiles {}| grep 80'
```

'echo examining process PID' will be printed before each search, so once you see an output referencing port 80, you'll know which process is holding the handle.

Alternatively use:

```
ps -ef| grep $USER|awk '{print $2}'| xargs -I '{}' sh -c 'echo examining process {}; pfiles {}| grep 80'
```

Since 'pfiles' might not like that you're trying to access other user's processes, unless you're root of course.

Comment: first line is useful for me.

Answer (score 4):

Mavroprovato's answer reports more than only the listening ports. Listening ports are sockets without a peer. The following Perl program reports only the listening ports. It works for me on SunOS 5.10.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
##
## Search the processes which are listening on the given port.
##
## For SunOS 5.10.
##

use strict;
use warnings;

die "Port missing" unless $#ARGV >= 0;
my $port = int($ARGV[0]);
die "Invalid port" unless $port > 0;

my @pids;
map { push @pids, $_ if $_ > 0; } map { int($_) } `ls /proc`;

foreach my $pid (@pids) {
    open (PF, "pfiles $pid 2>/dev/null |") 
        || warn "Can not read pfiles $pid";
    $_ = <PF>;
    my $fd;
    my $type;
    my $sockname;
    my $peername;
    my $report = sub {
        if (defined $fd) {
            if (defined $sockname && ! defined $peername) {
                print "$pid $type $sockname\n"; } } };
    while (<PF>) {
        if (/^\s*(\d+):.*$/) {
            &$report();
            $fd = int ($1);
            undef $type;
            undef $sockname;
            undef $peername; }
        elsif (/(SOCK_DGRAM|SOCK_STREAM)/) { $type = $1; }
        elsif (/sockname: AF_INET[6]? (.*)  port: $port/) {
            $sockname = $1; }
        elsif (/peername: AF_INET/) { $peername = 1; } }
    &$report();
    close (PF); }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
# This is a little script based on the "pfiles" solution that prints the PID and PORT.

pfiles `ls /proc` 2>/dev/null | awk "/^[^ \\t]/{smatch=\$0;next}/port:[ \\t]*${1}/{print smatch, \$0}{next}"
```

Answer (score 3):

From Solaris 11.2 onwards you can indeed do this with the `netstat` command. Have a look [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/casper/entry/solaris_11_2_user_pid). The `-u` switch is what you are looking for.

If you are on a lower version of Solaris then - as others have pointed out - the Solaris way of doing this is some kind of script wrapper around `pfiles` command. Beware though that `pfiles` command halts the process for a split second in order to inspect it. For 99.9% of processes this is unimportant. Unfortunately we have a process that will give a core dump if it is hit with a `pfiles` command so we are a bit cautious about using the command. Your situation may be totally different if you are in the 99.9%, meaning you can safely use the `pfiles` command.

Comment: Yep. I stand corrected. I've updated the answer. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

netstat on Solaris will not tell you this, nor will older versions of lsof, but if you download and build/install a newer version of lsof, this can tell you that.

```
$ lsof -v
lsof version information:
    revision: 4.85
    latest revision: ftp://lsof.itap.purdue.edu/pub/tools/unix/lsof/
    latest FAQ: ftp://lsof.itap.purdue.edu/pub/tools/unix/lsof/FAQ
    latest man page: ftp://lsof.itap.purdue.edu/pub/tools/unix/lsof/lsof_man
    configuration info: 64 bit kernel
    constructed: Fri Mar 7 10:32:54 GMT 2014
    constructed by and on: user@hostname
    compiler: gcc
    compiler version: 3.4.3 (csl-sol210-3_4-branch+sol_rpath)
    8<- - - - ***SNIP*** - - -
```

With this you can use the -i option:

```
$ lsof -i:22
COMMAND   PID     USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE   SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
sshd      521     root    3u  IPv6 0xffffffff89c67580        0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
sshd     5090     root    3u  IPv6 0xffffffffa8668580   0t322598  TCP host.domain.com:ssh->21.43.65.87:52364 (ESTABLISHED)
sshd     5091   johngh    4u  IPv6 0xffffffffa8668580   0t322598  TCP host.domain.com:ssh->21.43.65.87:52364 (ESTABLISHED)
```

Which shows you exactly what you're asking for.

I had a problem yesterday with a crashed Jetty (Java) process, which only left 2 files in its /proc/[PID] directory (psinfo & usage).

pfiles failed to find the process (because the date it needed was not there)

lsof found it for me.

Comment: I do `lsof -P -i -n | grep LISTEN`

Answer (score 1):

You might not want to, but your best bet is to grab the sunfreeware CD and install lsof.

Other than that, yes you can grovel around in /proc with a shell script.

Comment: Does Sun's implementation of lsof stop target processes (like pfiles, et al, does?)

Comment: @Randall: I have no idea, as I no longer have easy access to solaris systems.  I would doubt it -- it's not written by sun, unlike the p* tools.

Answer (score 1):

I think the first answer is the best
I wrote my own shell script developing this idea :

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ $# -ne 1 ]
then
    echo "Sintaxis:\n\t"
    echo " $0 {port to search in process }"
    exit
else
    MYPORT=$1
    for i in `ls /proc`
    do

       pfiles $i | grep port | grep "port: $MYPORT" > /dev/null
       if [ $? -eq 0 ]
         then
           echo " Port $MYPORT founded in $i proccess !!!\n\n"
           echo "Details\n\t"
           pfiles $i | grep port | grep "port: $MYPORT"
           echo "\n\t"
           echo "Process detail: \n\t"
           ps -ef | grep $i  | grep -v grep
       fi
    done
fi
```

Comment: Your script can be heavily simplified, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13246309/how-to-get-process-id-attached-with-particular-port-in-sunos

Answer (score 0):

Most probly sun's administrative server..
It's usually bundled along with sun's directory and a few other webmin-ish stuff that is in the default installation

Answer (score 0):

This is sort of an indirect approach, but you could see if a website loads on your web browser of choice from whatever is running on port 80.  Or you could telnet to port 80 and see if you get a response that gives you a clue as to what is running on that port and you can go shut it down.  Since port 80 is the default port for http traffic chances are there is some sort of http server running there by default, but there's no guarantee.

Answer (score 0):

using below script to identify the port number and related process id:

```
# sh port_scan_pid.sh 22

#!/bin/bash
Hostnames=`uname -n | cut -d. -f1`
port=$1
OS=`uname -s`
printf "+---------------+--------+-------+-----------+----------------------------------+\n"
printf "| %-13s | %-6s | %-5s | %-9s | %-32s |\n" "HostName" "PID" "PORT" "USER" "COMMAND"
printf "+---------------+--------+-------+-----------+----------------------------------+\n"
for Process_id in `ls /proc`
do
pfiles $Process_id 2>/dev/null | grep AF_INET | grep -w "$port" > /dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then

prid_user=`ps -o user -p $Process_id | tr -d ' '| tail -1`
prid_command=`ps -o comm -p $Process_id | tr -d ' '| tail -1`

printf "| %-13s | %-6s | %-5s | %-9s | %-32s |\n"  "$Hostnames" "$Process_id" "$port" "$prid_user" "$prid_command"

else
echo "$Hostnames | $OS | $port no PID found" > /dev/null 2>&1
fi
done
printf "+---------------+--------+-------+-----------+----------------------------------+\n"
```

Output is

```
root@NODE1:~# sh port_scan_pid.sh 22
+----------+--------+-------+-------+
| HostName | PID    | PORT  | OS    |
+----------+--------+-------+-------+
| NODE1    | 25065  | 22    | SunOS |
| NODE1    | 25068  | 22    | SunOS |
| NODE1    | 693    | 22    | SunOS |
+----------+--------+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the perfect script which will help to identify list of ports, related PID and process name owner of the process for SUN Solaris systems.

**sh ports-process-user-SUNOS.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
Hostnames=`uname -n | cut -d. -f1`
OS=`uname -s`

printf "+--------------+-----------+------------+-----------------+---------------------------------------------------------+\n"
printf "| %-12s | %-09s | %-010s | %-15s | %-55s |\n" "HostName" "PORT" "PID" "USER" "COMMAND"
printf "+--------------+-----------+------------+-----------------+---------------------------------------------------------+\n"

netstat -an| grep 'LISTEN'|awk '{print $1}'| sed 's/^127.0.0.1.//;s/^*.//'|sort -nu >/tmp/file.txt
# Read the file line by line
while read port; do

for Process_id in `ls /proc`
do
pfiles $Process_id 2>/dev/null | grep AF_INET | grep -w "$port" > /dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then

prid_user=`ps -o user -p $Process_id | tr -d ' '| tail -1`
prid_command=`ps -o comm -p $Process_id | tr -d ' '| tail -1`

printf "| %-12s | %-09s | %-010s | %-15s | %-55s |\n"  "$Hostnames" "$port" "$Process_id" "$prid_user" "$prid_command"

else
echo "$Hostnames | $OS | $port no PID found" > /dev/null 2>&1
fi
done
done < /tmp/file.txt
printf "+--------------+-----------+------------+-----------------+---------------------------------------------------------+\n"
```

Answer (score -3):

If you have access to `netstat`, that can do precisely that.

Comment: Unfortunately it won't on solaris.  You can use it to show all the open sockets, and their state, but not which process has them open.