# error while starting glassfish server

Tags: glassfish

this is my first post 
Hope will get solution.

I am getting below exceptions while starting glassfish server on solaris m/c and server is not starting.

After searching some of the blogs i found that it could be resolved by restarted m/c.

I want to find the cause...

Please help ...

---

[#|2011-05-10T18:54:00.212+0300|SEVERE|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.resource.corba.ee.S1AS-ORB.rpc.transport|_ThreadID=1
0;_ThreadName=main;all interfaces;3700;;_RequestID=7ad87260-643c-4341-9221-716f58687949;|"IOP00410216: (COMM_FAILURE) **Unable
to create IIOP listener on the specified host/port: all interfaces/3700"
org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 216**  completed: No
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.createListenerFailed(ORBUtilSystemException.java:3187)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.createListenerFailed(ORBUtilSystemException.java:3207)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelAcceptorImpl.initialize(SocketOrChannelAcceptorImpl.java:182)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.CorbaTransportManagerImpl.getAcceptors(CorbaTransportManagerImpl.java:236)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.CorbaTransportManagerImpl.addToIORTemplate(CorbaTransportManagerImpl.java:253)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.oa.ObjectAdapterBase.initializeTemplate(ObjectAdapterBase.java:127)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.oa.toa.TOAImpl.(TOAImpl.java:107)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.oa.toa.TOAFactory.getTOA(TOAFactory.java:98)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ORBImpl.connect(ORBImpl.java:1664)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.presentation.rmi.StubAdapter.connect(StubAdapter.java:212)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ORBImpl.getIOR(ORBImpl.java:2115)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ORBImpl.getFVDCodeBaseIOR(ORBImpl.java:987)
        at com.sun.enterprise.util.ORBManager.initORB(ORBManager.java:556)
        at com.sun.enterprise.util.ORBManager.getORB(ORBManager.java:278)
        at com.sun.enterprise.util.ORBManager.getORB(ORBManager.java:289)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.ondemand.EjbServiceGroup.createORB(EjbServiceGroup.java:511)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.ondemand.EjbServiceGroup.startORB(EjbServiceGroup.java:437)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.ondemand.EjbServiceGroup._start(EjbServiceGroup.java:156)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.ondemand.EjbServiceGroup.start(EjbServiceGroup.java:143)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.ondemand.ServiceGroup$1.run(ServiceGroup.java:193)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.ondemand.ServiceGroup.startChildren(ServiceGroup.java:190)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.ondemand.MainServiceGroup.start(MainServiceGroup.java:58)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.ondemand.ServerEntryListenerImpl.notifyEntry(ServerEntryListenerImpl.java:85)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.ondemand.entry.ServerEntryHelper.sendEvent(ServerEntryHelper.java:75)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.ondemand.entry.ServerEntryHelper.generateStartUpEntryContext(ServerEntryHelper.java:64)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.ondemand.OnDemandServer.generateEntryContext(OnDemandServer.java:154)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.ondemand.OnDemandServer.onStartup(OnDemandServer.java:133)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.PEMain.run(PEMain.java:409)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.PEMain.main(PEMain.java:336)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.PELaunch.main(PELaunch.java:415)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:119)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:59)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:52)
        at com.sun.enterprise.iiop.IIOPSSLSocketFactory.createServerSocket(IIOPSSLSocketFactory.java:301)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelAcceptorImpl.initialize(SocketOrChannelAcceptorImpl.java:175)
        ... 32 more
|#]

[#|2011-05-10T18:54:00.254+0300|WARNING|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.resource.corba.ee.*INITIALIZING*.rpc.presentation|_
ThreadID=10;_ThreadName=main;;_RequestID=7ad87260-643c-4341-9221-716f58687949;|"IOP02310202: (OBJ_ADAPTER) Error in connectin
g servant to ORB"
org.omg.CORBA.OBJ_ADAPTER:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 202  completed: No
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.orbConnectError(ORBUtilSystemException.java:10263)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.orbConnectError(ORBUtilSystemException.java:10281)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ORBImpl.connect(ORBImpl.java:1666)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.presentation.rmi.StubAdapter.connect(StubAdapter.java:212)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ORBImpl.getIOR(ORBImpl.java:2115)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ORBImpl.getFVDCodeBaseIOR(ORBImpl.java:987)
        at com.sun.enterprise.util.ORBManager.initORB(ORBManager.java:556)
        at com.sun.enterprise.util.ORBManager.getORB(ORBManager.java:278)
        at com.sun.enterprise.util.ORBManager.getORB(ORBManager.java:289)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.ondemand.EjbServiceGroup.createORB(EjbServiceGroup.java:511)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.ondemand.EjbServiceGroup.startORB(EjbServiceGroup.java:437)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.ondemand.EjbServiceGroup._start(EjbServiceGroup.java:156)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.ondemand.EjbServiceGroup.start(EjbServiceGroup.java:143)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.ondemand.ServiceGroup$1.run(ServiceGroup.java:193)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.ondemand.ServiceGroup.startChildren(ServiceGroup.java:190)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.ondemand.MainServiceGroup.start(MainServiceGroup.java:58)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.ondemand.ServerEntryListenerImpl.notifyEntry(ServerEntryListenerImpl.java:85)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.ondemand.entry.ServerEntryHelper.sendEvent(ServerEntryHelper.java:75)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.ondemand.entry.ServerEntryHelper.generateStartUpEntryContext(ServerEntryHelper.java:64)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.ondemand.OnDemandServer.generateEntryContext(OnDemandServer.java:154)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.ondemand.OnDemandServer.onStartup(OnDemandServer.java:133)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.PEMain.run(PEMain.java:409)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.PEMain.main(PEMain.java:336)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.PELaunch.main(PELaunch.java:415)
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 216  completed: No
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.createListenerFailed(ORBUtilSystemException.java:3187)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.createListenerFailed(ORBUtilSystemException.java:3207)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelAcceptorImpl.initialize(SocketOrChannelAcceptorImpl.java:182)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.CorbaTransportManagerImpl.getAcceptors(CorbaTransportManagerImpl.java:236)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.CorbaTransportManagerImpl.addToIORTemplate(CorbaTransportManagerImpl.java:253)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.oa.ObjectAdapterBase.initializeTemplate(ObjectAdapterBase.java:127)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.oa.toa.TOAImpl.(TOAImpl.java:107)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.oa.toa.TOAFactory.getTOA(TOAFactory.java:98)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ORBImpl.connect(ORBImpl.java:1664)
        ... 26 more
**Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use**
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Native Method)

Thanks and regards,
Ali

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the domain's ports without starting glassfish, you can do this by editing the xml domain's config file

```
domainName/config/domain.xml
```

Hope this will help you.
Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

You should probably start by finding out [what process is using port 3700](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91169/what-process-is-listening-on-a-certain-port-on-solaris) and find out if you can kill it.

If you cannot kill that process, you can use [asadmin's create-domain subcommand](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19879-01/820-4332/6nfq988pk/index.html) to create a new domain that does not use the 'standard GlassFish ports'... The easiest way to do that is with the --portbase option.

Comment: Thanks vkraemer, 
my problem is resolved :)

I killed all the process running under glassfish and started my domain and it worked !!!
probably one of the domain was already bound to that port !