# Details about S_IFSOCK

Tags: sockets, solaris, system-calls, tcp, solaris-10

I truss'ed a stuck process and found the following:

```
19326/2:        read(197, 0xFFFFFC7FFE05E080, 8192) (sleeping...)

$  pfiles 19326|grep 197:
 197: S_IFSOCK mode:0666 dev:303,0 ino:33422 uid:0 gid:0 size:0
```

how to get details about this S_IFSOCK? i.e., the source, destination IPs, the TCP　port it's listening to/trying to connect to.. etc.

Comment: You should be able to find this via pfiles, see e.g. discussion at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/91169/what-process-is-listening-on-a-certain-port-on-solaris. My usual go-to for this would be lsof, but I gather you would need a newer version than the default for solaris 10.

Answer (score 0):

pfiles prints additional details on following lines that your grep command isn't showing.

For instance, on a Solaris 10 machine here:

```
   4: S_IFSOCK mode:0666 dev:276,0 ino:58146 uid:0 gid:0 size:0
      O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK
        SOCK_STREAM
        SO_REUSEADDR,SO_KEEPALIVE,SO_SNDBUF(49152),SO_RCVBUF(49232)
        sockname: AF_INET6 ::ffff:10.134.73.106  port: 22
        peername: AF_INET6 ::ffff:10.132.136.78  port: 62714
```